# Can the following sentence be literal (or is it a metaphor)

Tags: metaphors

I have the following sentence which I *thought* was implying that a metaphor is like a moustache

- Today I learnt how to wax a metaphor

Having checked through [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wax) the only literal (i.e. transitive verb) meaning of "wax" that may be applied is:

> 5 (transitive, archaic, usually of a musical or oral performance) To
>   record

But the term is archaic, and I can't quite place the idea of **learning to record a metaphor** (rather than recording its expression).

---

1. Is the above bulleted statement a metaphor?
2. Is that because it cannot be read literally?

Comment: I suppose that it can be read literally but the oddity of what it denotes would suggest a metaphorical reading of it all the same - this time with an alternative definition of "wax" (i.e. to record). but then it's a judgment between metaphorical meanings, rather than a literal and figurative reading

Comment: You need to give a lot more context, the surrounding paragraph and motivation. Another explanation is that it may be poor usage (i.e. the _attempt_ at a metaphor may just not work).

Comment: ok thanks! i think if it is grasped as a metaphor, then the target audience would understand - given their shared assumptions about metaphors and moustaches too confusing to really list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the statement

> Today I learnt how to wax a metaphor

is itself a metaphor.

Without more context, it's not possible to say for sure what the intended meaning of 'to wax' is in that metaphor, but the most likely meaning is

> To increase [the metaphor] gradually in size, ..., strength, or intensity....

[wax. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved December 30 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wax .]

Another possible meaning, that seems less likely to me, is

> To coat, treat, or polish with wax.

(op. cit.)

In this latter sense, 'to wax' a metaphor would mean to make it more slippery, as with waxed skis, or more polished, as with floors.

The statement is a metaphor, but whether or not it can

> ... be read literally

does not bear directly on whether or not the statement is or is not a metaphor.

1. Other things than metaphors cannot be read literally. One prominent example of another thing that cannot be read literally is nonsense, which, if read metaphorically, is no longer nonsense.
2. Some metaphors can be read literally, but are nonetheless metaphors. This is by far the most common case for metaphors. An example is your idea that 'waxing' in the sense of 'recording' is *literal*. The actual referent of 'to wax' in that sense is 'to record in wax', which itself refers to the substance used for phonographic recording. Thus 'to wax' in the sense you took for literal means 'to record [on wax]'--but phonographic recordings long ago ceased to be made in wax:

> A decade later, Edison developed a greatly improved phonograph that employed a hollow **wax** cylinder instead of a foil sheet. This proved to be both a better-sounding and far more useful device. The **wax** phonograph cylinder created the recorded sound market at the end of the 1880s and dominated it through the early years of the 20th century.

(From [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramophone_record).)

A metaphor is a metaphor because it is

> a poetically or rhetorically ambitious use of words, a *figurative* as opposed to *literal* use.

(See Hills, David, "Metaphor", *The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy* (Winter 2012 Edition), Edward N. Zalta (ed.), URL = http://plato.stanford.edu/archives/win2012/entries/metaphor/.)

A deceptively simple but nonetheless complete definition of metaphor is this from [*Silva Rhetoricae*](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/M/metaphor.htm):

> A comparison made by referring to one thing as another.

In the case of your example, a metaphor is referred to with a verb that applies to skis, or floors, or another thing entirely.

Comment: thanks. you point out the obvious ambiguity to identifying the tenor. what is the term for this property? may i also ask, supposing the figure draws a likeness between metaphors and moustaches, if the vehicle *includes* its being waxed, or not ?

Comment: @user3293056, the tenor is metaphor (as subject); the vehicle is the waxing. If the context makes clear that metaphors are being referred to as (not compared to or likened to--different figure) moustaches, then yes, moustaches are part of the vehicle. The terminology is perhaps clearer when thought of as *primary* (metaphor) and *secondary* (waxing) subjects--terminology from Beardsley rather than Richards. See the article linked from the Enc. of Philos.

Comment: @user3293056, if the vehicle/secondary subject is explicitly a moustache or moustaches, the metaphorical sense of 'to wax' is 'to shape [a metaphor] as a moustache is shaped after being impregnated with wax'.

Comment: so in the SEP example of implicit metaphor the entire focus of the sentence "I shall flutter helplessly closer and closer until you burn me to death at last." is the secondary subject ? that seems wrong

Comment: @user3293056, two metaphors are involved, although they are linked into one: "I" and "you" are primary subjects; "flutter" and "burn" are secondary; they correlate with "moth" and "flame" or "candle" ("I" and "you") implicitly.

Comment: @user3293056, The whole thing implicitly refers the attraction of "I" to "you" to a "moth's" attraction to a "flame" (or "candle"); that is the implicit metaphor, referring to *self-destructive human romantic attraction to another human* (primary) as *a moth's self-destructive attraction to light* (secondary).

Comment: yeah if so then i misunderstood the article, which is frustrating. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

"To wax a metaphor" may be poetic, but it is not a metaphor. From the OED:

*Of a quality, activity, event, etc.: To come into being, spring up, begin, arise, occur. Also with up. Of the day: To appear, dawn.*

and

*to wax forth, to be born or created.*

So, your example *Today I learnt how to wax a metaphor* means, literally, that *Today I learnt how to (create/bring into being/cause to appear or occur) a metaphor*. Archaic for sure, but not metaphoric.

A metaphor is a sentence like *all the world is a stage* which works by viewing the world as having some of the characteristics of a stage, and has the form of the world being spoken of as a stage when it only resembles a stage, which makes it different to a simile which normally uses "as" or "like". Keep in mind that the [conceptual view of metaphor](http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~israel/lakoff-ConTheorMetaphor.pdf) as anything that maps the characteristics of A onto B covers a much wider range of forms.

In your example, nothing is being spoken of as being something else, nor is any characteristic being transferred to something else, so it is not a metaphor by either the traditional or the conceptual model.

Comment: this is not here http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wax or here https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wax

Comment: i found the hit and that definition is "obsolete"

Comment: i downvoted cos your answer needs more explanation of when an expression should be read as obsolete rather than metaphoric. obsolete means "no longer in use in the English language", and i struggle to believe that it should be read that way

Comment: @user3293056 ~ first, Oxford Dictionaries is not the Oxford English Dictionary. Second, what makes you think that an archaic term means it must be a metaphor? The two things are totally unrelated. There is a lot of obsolete language in use right now in legal, ceremonial, or literate contexts, and 'wax' is still in current use to describe the growing phase of the moon -> http://www.moonconnection.com/moon_phases.phtml. Thirdly, I have explained what defines a metaphor. If you think "I learnt how to wax a metaphor" is metaphoric, please go ahead and explain it to me.

Comment: i'm confused... i already asked (imho politely) for when a term should be read in its obsolete sense as opposed to metaphorically, and i make it clear i thought that the statement in the OP expressed likeness between a metaphor and a moustache - by saying that i learnt to wax [that the vehicle of moustache is implied by the metaphor's focus]. yes it is an unusual etc. comparison

Comment: As I explained in my post, with a link, for your example to be a metaphor would require some property of wax to be transferred to 'a metaphor'. If you must use I.A. Richards concepts from 1958, wax would be the vehicle an the tenor would be... what? This is what I am asking you to explain: what property of wax do you think is being transferred to 'a metaphor', because if there is none it not a metaphor by definition. In my post I gave an example "all the world is a stage." Some properties of a stage (actors, audience) are transferred to the world. Where is the transfer of properties in yours?

Comment: if you read the discussion above, i was saying that 'wax' is a focus meant to *imply* a separate vehicle - of moustaches

Comment: So you are inventing a vehicle that isn't actually in this 'metaphor' of yours? Okay -  we can run with that. Explain what properties of moustache you imagine are being transferred to 'a metaphor', because if there are none it is still not a metaphor by definition.

Comment: yes it's totally reasonable to only "imply" the vehicle, see the SEP article. e.g. moustaches are stylish and decorative.

Comment: To be a metaphor, properties need to be transferred regardless of the mechanism. So, your interpretation is that "Today I learned how to wax a metaphor" means "Today I learned how to give a metaphor the characteristics of a stylish moustache"? According to Grice, and Sperber and Wilson, a metaphor is recognised because it has no literal meaning ("He is a bulldozer!) I have shown that this sentence has a literal meaning so it fails as a metaphor. It simply references the well-known "wax lyrical" phrase: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/wax-lyrical

Comment: thanks for the comment on grice etc., but no again you seem to misunderstand that the vehicle is implied. a vehicle can be implied, right ?

Comment: as to it having a literal meaning, i don't think you have, you've shown it to have a literal meaning outside standard english. also the sense it is used in "wax lyrical" cannot be grammatically applied to the statement in the OP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33681/discussion-between-user3293056-and-roaring-fish).

Comment: "The moon is waxing" is not non-standard, as the link I provided shows. "He is waxing lyrical" is not non-standard, as my link to Collins shows. I understand very well how metaphors work - it is you that is struggling with it, or I suspect deliberately refusing to understand. "Waxing a metaphor" is simply a play on words, drawing a comparison with "waxing lyrical" -> http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wax-lyrical. It is just an allusion. It is not a metaphor because no properties are transferred to 'a metaphor'.

Comment: i learnt to wax a lyric would be metaphorical, because "waxing" in this sense must be used with an adjective. i think you are struggling to understand tbh

Comment: i don't mean to be rude, we're both repeating ourselves which suggests at least one perhaps both of us, misunderstands the other. all i meant, is that it is reasonable to suppose that it cannot be taken literally. your comments have been useful, if a tiny bit IMVHO incomplete - to be perfect. i only downvoted because, in addition, i disagree with your opinion - IMO in a legitimate way

Comment: Definition of wax
intransitive *verb*
1
a :  to increase in size, numbers, strength, prosperity, or intensity b :  to grow in volume or duration c :  to grow toward full development
2:  to increase in phase or intensity —used chiefly of the moon, other satellites, and inferior planets
3:  to assume a (specified) characteristic, quality, or state :  become <wax indignant> <wax poetic>  Verbs don't need adjectives, and there is nothing metaphorical about developing  a metaphor or lyric. Your stubborn refusal to understand is based on denying that wax, as a verb meaning to grow or develop exists.

Comment: i would've thought *wax a metaphor* had 'metaphor' as an object, so cannot literally mean the intransitive sense of "grow"