# Do dictionaries use polysemes in definitions without sufficiently explaining which sense/s is/are involved?

Tags: dictionaries

I want to know if the definitions grouped in a dictionary are stated in unequivocal language.

e.g. *Wax* has the following definition:

> [literary] become larger or stronger. *his anger waxed*

– Is only one sense of "stronger" meant here?

Presumably:

> became more intense.

I ask both to improve my use of dictionaries, and because I will find it baffling if an English language learner needs to work out which single meaning a term appearing in a definition has.

Comment: What is the question here? The meaning of stronger or the meaning of wax? Both can be found by reference to a dictionary.

Comment: the question is whether dictionaries pun, and what exactly i mean that should be illustrated by the example. also, i included an explicit question in the body of the post

Comment: You are quoting, though in a quite sloppy way from ODO concerning the verb *wax*. The main reference is to the moon phases - then as an aside it says *LITERARY - becomes larger or stronger: "his anger waxed"*. That sounds a perfectly reasonable way to explain its use. I don't see where any "pun" arises.

Comment: Just a heads-up. You received 2 close-votes and 1 downvote. Please edit your question focusing on English Language and its Usage.

Comment: @WS2 i'm sorry you don't understand the question but i think it is clearly stated. i would suggest not psychologising the question, working out why anyone would care about this definition of wax. it's meant to illustrate the question, not exhaust it

Comment: Your question in the body is "Is only one meaning of "stronger" meant here?" Looking in a dictionary should answer that.

Comment: @RoaringFish sorry but i don't understand, you're more than welcome to answer the question by quoting from a dictionary

Comment: @user3293056 ~ despite 3 close votes and a down vote you are still missing the point: there is no question here to be answered. If your difficulty is with the meaning of 'stronger', you can use a dictionary. We are here to answer questions, not look up references for you. I suggest that you read this page -> http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i think i'm misunderstanding how to use the site, i'm (IMHO clearly) not asking what 'stronger' means, only how it is meant in the definition of "wax" - specifically whether it is used *in only one sense*

Comment: @RoaringFish please do explain?

Comment: Then, you have an answer in the dictionary. How many definitions are there for **wax** as a **verb**? How many example sentences are there? What is it that you don't understand among them?

Comment: this is frustrating... i am asking whether the definition e.g. "literary become larger or stronger. "his anger waxed"" uses its terms i.e. "become" "larger" "stronger" etc. in only one sense

Comment: Then go to a dictionary, provide the entry for 'stronger', and explain what part of it you find hard to understand.

Comment: Essentially, yes: you will often need to make a judgement-call on which sense or senses of certain words in a dictionary definition applies or apply. Dictionaries for learners exist, which probably take more care with their word-choice (and include fewer headwords). But eventually, a perfect dictionary cannot exist (words being infinitely polysemous) and no dictionary of reasonable size could cater for all denotations even.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth oh ok, judgment is called for - and **yes** it can be polysemous !!

Comment: A dictionary isn't a logical program that is compiled to a feature perfect executable of a native language speaker. There may be mistakes in the entries (a compiler error), and there may be co- or o-missions in definitions and unresolved expansions or circularities (run-time or feature problems). A dictionary lives in the context of native language speakers, it does not allow a non-native speaker to reproduce meaning. So the direct answer is 'maybe, more than one sense of stronger is meant'. Other relevant words are 'increased'. Sometimes you need to read between the lines.

Comment: @Mitch that's helpful, tho i will add that i'm a native speaker of english and it would help me (even or especially with common words)

Comment: The more common a word, the more likely it has many separate meanings (look at pages of entries of 'set' or 'go' in a dictionary)

Comment: Stronger is a comparative. How many meanings can it have?

Comment: ikr... ftr is has 6 separate definitions, and many more senses

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33805/discussion-on-question-by-user3293056-do-dictionaries-use-polysemes-in-definitio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary isn't a logical program that is compiled to a feature perfect executable of a native language speaker. There may be mistakes in the entries (a compiler error), and there may be co- or o-missions in definitions and unresolved expansions or circularities (run-time or feature problems). A dictionary lives in the context of native language speakers, it does not allow a non-native speaker to reproduce meaning. Note [the definition of 'a' (at least at one place)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a) which uses 'a'.

So the direct answer is that, **yes, maybe more than one sense of 'stronger' could be meant**. (I'm not sure which other meanings of stronger you're thinking of). Another relevant word is 'increased'. It's all a metaphor of 'waxing', of the moon on its way to becoming full. And there, 'waxing' is probably a metaphor for something earlier. [(from etymonline, it seems 'waxing' has always meant something like increasing, cognate with 'augment')](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wax)

Comment: thanks for directly answering the question, though i'm not sure what you are referring to with the comment about its metaphorical content

Comment: Do you ask about the metaphor of waxing or about metaphor in general?

Comment: in the other question i was asking cos i was interested in 'metaphor' (in general, outside its alleged analogy with moustaches), but like i suggested - i don't immediately see the relevance of what you added on it here (either to my example, or the question that prompted it)

Comment: OK. So both I guess. waxing = moon increasing in size. by analogy 'waxing' is used often for anything increasing (with the possible connotation that it may go in cycles, decreasing too). In general, metaphor comes from people using a word slightly outside of its strict definition. A horse is an animal with a certain look. A sawhorse has a vague similarity to that shape. It could have been called a saw dog or saw elephant, but most likely not a saw bucket. I, on the other hand, don't understand your reference to mustache though!

Comment: in reference to a prior thread http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296729/can-the-following-sentence-be-literal-or-is-it-a-metaphor

Comment: Oh, well, why did you think we'd understand that reference to 'moustache'? You need to give the context earlier rather than expecting us to ask.

Comment: ok just assumed you would have seen the recent thread :) apologies.

Comment: No problem. You can't assume that everybody has read everything. Also, just make it easier for others.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that words are always in context.  As our English gets better so we understand more easily which, of the possible meanings of any given word, is the right one.  In your example '*wax*' is being linked with '*anger*'.   So '*become stronger*', in its sense of '*become more intense*', is a possible translation for 'wax'.  Of course, 'become stronger' can be used in contexts when 'wax' would not be an alternative ("As he recovered from his illness he became stronger").

Comment: If you consider it appropriate to do so, would you (or @Mitch) consider adding a sentence or two to your answer(s) that includes "wax and wane"? It might help provide a fuller understanding of this use of "wax" for the OP.

Comment: +1. In other words, this definition is trying to help you understand occurrences you might encounter, but apparently *not* to help you write new sentences with this word.

Comment: @MarkHubbard - the OP is not especially interested in the meaning and use of 'wax'.  The focus, as I have understood it, is on how dictionary definitions communicate meaning (especially to someone for whom the meaning of *all* English words is not clear).